# Will health beta ever pass the beta phase?

Tags: discussion, beta-phase

The stats for health beta look pretty low. Is there a chance that things will turn around?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a question better asked on [Meta Health SE](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com) and I note that there is already a question on the same subject which has been posted there:

[Is Health.SE sick?](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332/is-health-se-sick)